# How can I properly execute a shell command in PHP?

Tags: php, shell

I have the following shell command:

```
comm -3 <(sort file1) <(sort file2) | sed -e 's/^[ \t]*//' | awk -F , '{if (a[$1]) {print "^"$1","} {a[$1] = $0}}' > data2.txt
```

If I run it through `exec` and escape all the `

`exec('comm -3 <(sort file1) <(sort file2) | sed -e \'s/^[ \t]*//\' | awk -F , \'{if (a[$1]) {print "^"$1","} {a[$1] = $0}}\' > data2.txt');`

It fails:

```
sh: 1: Syntax error: "(" unexpected
```

If I escape the curly braces, the shell command itself fails:

```
awk: cmd. line:1: {if \(a[$1]\) {print "^"$1","} {a[$1] = $0}}
awk: cmd. line:1:     ^ backslash not last character on line
awk: cmd. line:1: {if \(a[$1]\) {print "^"$1","} {a[$1] = $0}}
awk: cmd. line:1:     ^ syntax error
sh: 1: cannot open (sort: No such file
```

How can I successfully run this shell command with PHP and `exec` function?

Comment: Try with basic simple command to see the process. Use `$output = shell_exec('ls);` and see output. You can use `phpseclib` instead of exec and shell_exec because its not good to activate exec() in your server.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue by using `bash -c` and then escaping the single quotes:

`bash -c 'comm -3 <(sort {$current_file}) <(sort {$new_file}) | sed -e '"'"'s/^[ \t]*//'"'"' | awk -F , '"'"'{if (a[$1]) {print "^"$1","} {a[$1] = $0}}'"'"' > {$meta_file}'`